# How to rename a list of files to a specific name format?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of files

> 1_test.pdf, 2_test.pdf, 3_test.pdf, 4_test.pdf, 5_test.pdf, 6_test.pdf, 7_test.pdf, 8_test.pdf, 9_test.pdf, 10_test.pdf.

I need to rename them to a format

> test_f0001.pdf, test_f0002.pdf, test_f0003.pdf, test_f0004.pdf, test_f0005.pdf, test_f0006.pdf, test_f0007.pdf, test_f0008.pdf, test_f0009.pdf, test_f0010.pdf.

Is it possible to rename them without copying or moving the files?
Thank you!

Comment: Isn't "renaming" a file the same as "moving it to a different name in the same directory"?

Comment: @JoeSewell, does the file move location on disk when you rename it?

Comment: @JoeSewell That depends on the OS - Unix based OS (from a user point of view) consider it moving to a different name, even if the path changes as long as the filesystem remains the same (and the API function is actually named `rename`). Windows based OS has a specific and different rename command (from a user POV) for when the folder doesn't change. Strangely the Win32 API is named Move :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as 'renaming' when it comes to files, you have to use move.

So, simply,

```
var file = @"A.txt";
File.Move(file, "A1.txt");
```

would rename your `A.txt` to `A1.txt`.

### EDIT

For renaming the files, you can manipulate strings. Assuming your original files adhere to your example:

```
var file = "10_test.pdf";
int.TryParse(file.Split('_').ToList().ElementAt(0), out int num);
var rename = string.Format("test_f{0:0000}.pdf", num);
```

So this will change

> 10_test.pdf ==> test_f0010.pdf

and

> 1_test.pdf ==> test_f0001.pdf

The `{0:0000}` in the `string.Format()` tells it to print a number, filling it with leading zeros upto 4 digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.IO.File.Move` to rename a file, by moving it to the same directory with a new name (when renaming a file, you're technically changing the full path of the file).

For example:

```
private static void CustomRename(string directoryPath)
{
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath))
    {
        var basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
        var ext = Path.GetExtension(file);

        // If it doesn't have our extension, continue
        if (!ext.Equals(".pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) continue;

        var nameParts = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).Split('_');

        // If it doesn't have our required parts, continue
        if (nameParts.Length != 2) continue;

        var numericPart = nameParts[0];
        int number;

        // If the numeric part isn't numeric, continue
        if (!int.TryParse(numericPart, out number)) continue;

        // Create new file name and rename file by moving it
        var newName = $"{nameParts[1]}_f{number:0000}{ext}";

        File.Move(file, Path.Combine(basePath, newName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You need to move it:

```
System.IO.File.Move(oldNameFullPath, newNameFullPath);
```